# Oracle query percentage based on time range

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an Oracle query to count percentage below:

```
select to_char(ltrim(round((1 - n / c) * 100) || '%')) as total
  from (select count(*) c
          from wa_sew_tbl_emp_info
         where status = 'Attend'
           and shift = case
                  when to_char(sysdate, 'HH24:MI') >= '07:00'
                       and to_char(sysdate, 'HH24:MI') <= '19:29' then
                   'Morning'
                  when to_char(sysdate, 'HH24:MI') >= '19:30'
                       and to_char(sysdate, 'HH24:MI') <= '23:59' then
                   'Night'
                  when to_char(sysdate, 'HH24:MI') >= '00:00'
                       and to_char(sysdate, 'HH24:MI') <= '06:59' then
                   'Night'
               end)
      ,(select count(*) n
         from (select s.badgeid_fk
                 from wa_sew_tbl_emp_info s
                     ,wa_ga_tbl_employees e
                where s.badgeid_fk = e.badgeid
                  and s.status = 'Attend'
                  and s.shift = case
                         when to_char(sysdate, 'HH24:MI') >= '07:00'
                              and to_char(sysdate, 'HH24:MI') <= '19:29' then
                          'Morning'
                         when to_char(sysdate, 'HH24:MI') >= '19:30'
                              and to_char(sysdate, 'HH24:MI') <= '23:59' then
                          'Night'
                         when to_char(sysdate, 'HH24:MI') >= '00:00'
                              and to_char(sysdate, 'HH24:MI') <= '06:59' then
                          'Night'
                      end
                  and s.badgeid_fk not in
                      (select empid
                         from wa_sew_tbl_results
                        where system_date between to_date(case
                                                             when to_char(sysdate, 'HH24:MI') >= '07:00'
                                                                  and to_char(sysdate, 'HH24:MI') <= '19:29' then
                                                              to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD') || ' 07:00'
                                                             when to_char(sysdate, 'HH24:MI') >= '19:30'
                                                                  and to_char(sysdate, 'HH24:MI') <= '23:59' then
                                                              to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD') || ' 19:30'
                                                             when to_char(sysdate, 'HH24:MI') >= '00:00'
                                                                  and to_char(sysdate, 'HH24:MI') <= '06:59' then
                                                              to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD') || ' 00:00'
                                                          end
                                                         ,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI')
                          and to_date(case
                                         when to_char(sysdate, 'HH24:MI') >= '07:00'
                                              and to_char(sysdate, 'HH24:MI') <= '19:29' then
                                          to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD') || ' 19:29'
                                         when to_char(sysdate, 'HH24:MI') >= '19:30'
                                              and to_char(sysdate, 'HH24:MI') <= '23:59' then
                                          to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD') || ' 23:59'
                                         when to_char(sysdate, 'HH24:MI') >= '00:00'
                                              and to_char(sysdate, 'HH24:MI') <= '06:59' then
                                          to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD') || ' 06:59'
                                      end
                                     ,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI'))))
```

That query function is to get percentage.

AS you can see above code, Date will automatically set based on today date and time range.

The date time range query:
'07:00' - '19:29' OK
'19:30' - '23:59' OK

And now When We are on time: 00.00 - 06.59, I want query based on:
'19:30' - '23:59' with date yesterday AND
'00:00' - '06:59' with date today.

You can refer to this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5fb75/1/0)

Answer (score 1):

The problem with basing code on system date/time is that as soon as you set it up it becomes redundant. I don't think your sqlfiddle is very helpful as it returns 0%.

Additionally it really isn't clear what you are asking. Could you use something like the following to **articulate what you expect for each of the "s.ysdate" values** shown in the table below. Note that the columns y,y2,x1,x2 are extracted from your query.

available here at [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b62beb/55)

```
with S as (
        select to_date('2017-10-15 07:01:00','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') as ysdate from dual union all
        select to_date('2017-10-15 07:01:00','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')+ 1/24 from dual union all
        select to_date('2017-10-15 07:01:00','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')+ 2/24 from dual union all
        select to_date('2017-10-15 07:01:00','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')+ 3/24 from dual union all
        select to_date('2017-10-15 07:01:00','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')+ 4/24 from dual union all
        select to_date('2017-10-15 07:01:00','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')+ 5/24 from dual union all
        select to_date('2017-10-15 07:01:00','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')+ 6/24 from dual union all
        select to_date('2017-10-15 07:01:00','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')+ 7/24 from dual union all
        select to_date('2017-10-15 07:01:00','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')+ 8/24 from dual union all
        select to_date('2017-10-15 07:01:00','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')+ 9/24 from dual union all
        select to_date('2017-10-15 07:01:00','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')+10/24 from dual union all
        select to_date('2017-10-15 07:01:00','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')+11/24 from dual union all
        select to_date('2017-10-15 07:01:00','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')+12/24 from dual union all
        select to_date('2017-10-15 07:01:00','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')+13/24 from dual union all
        select to_date('2017-10-15 07:01:00','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')+14/24 from dual union all
        select to_date('2017-10-15 07:01:00','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')+15/24 from dual union all
        select to_date('2017-10-15 07:01:00','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')+16/24 from dual union all
        select to_date('2017-10-15 07:01:00','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')+17/24 from dual union all
        select to_date('2017-10-15 07:01:00','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')+18/24 from dual union all
        select to_date('2017-10-15 07:01:00','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')+19/24 from dual union all
        select to_date('2017-10-15 07:01:00','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')+20/24 from dual union all
        select to_date('2017-10-15 07:01:00','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')+21/24 from dual union all
        select to_date('2017-10-15 07:01:00','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')+22/24 from dual union all
        select to_date('2017-10-15 07:01:00','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')+23/24 from dual union all
        select to_date('2017-10-15 07:01:00','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')+24/24 from dual
          )
SELECT     
   s.ysdate "s.ysdate"
,  case
      when to_char(s.ysdate, 'HH24:MI') >= '07:00'
           and to_char(s.ysdate, 'HH24:MI') <= '19:29' then
       'Morning'
      when to_char(s.ysdate, 'HH24:MI') >= '19:30'
           and to_char(s.ysdate, 'HH24:MI') <= '23:59' then
       'Night'
      when to_char(s.ysdate, 'HH24:MI') >= '00:00'
           and to_char(s.ysdate, 'HH24:MI') <= '06:59' then
       'Night'
  end
  as y
, case
     when to_char(s.ysdate, 'HH24:MI') >= '07:00'
          and to_char(s.ysdate, 'HH24:MI') <= '19:29' then
      'Morning'
     when to_char(s.ysdate, 'HH24:MI') >= '19:30'
          and to_char(s.ysdate, 'HH24:MI') <= '23:59' then
      'Night'
     when to_char(s.ysdate, 'HH24:MI') >= '00:00'
          and to_char(s.ysdate, 'HH24:MI') <= '06:59' then
      'Night'
  end 
  y2
, to_date(case
             when to_char(s.ysdate, 'HH24:MI') >= '07:00'
                  and to_char(s.ysdate, 'HH24:MI') <= '19:29' then
              to_char(s.ysdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD') || ' 07:00'
             when to_char(s.ysdate, 'HH24:MI') >= '19:30'
                  and to_char(s.ysdate, 'HH24:MI') <= '23:59' then
              to_char(s.ysdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD') || ' 19:30'
             when to_char(s.ysdate, 'HH24:MI') >= '00:00'
                  and to_char(s.ysdate, 'HH24:MI') <= '06:59' then
              to_char(s.ysdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD') || ' 00:00'
          end
 ,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI')
 as x1
, to_date(case
             when to_char(s.ysdate, 'HH24:MI') >= '07:00'
                  and to_char(s.ysdate, 'HH24:MI') <= '19:29' then
              to_char(s.ysdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD') || ' 19:29'
             when to_char(s.ysdate, 'HH24:MI') >= '19:30'
                  and to_char(s.ysdate, 'HH24:MI') <= '23:59' then
              to_char(s.ysdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD') || ' 23:59'
             when to_char(s.ysdate, 'HH24:MI') >= '00:00'
                  and to_char(s.ysdate, 'HH24:MI') <= '06:59' then
              to_char(s.ysdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD') || ' 06:59'
          end
  ,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI')
  as x2
from s
order by 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b62beb/55/0)**:

```
|             s.ysdate |       Y |      Y2 |                   X1 |                   X2 |
|----------------------|---------|---------|----------------------|----------------------|
| 2017-10-15T07:01:00Z | Morning | Morning | 2017-10-15T07:00:00Z | 2017-10-15T19:29:00Z |
| 2017-10-15T08:01:00Z | Morning | Morning | 2017-10-15T07:00:00Z | 2017-10-15T19:29:00Z |
| 2017-10-15T09:01:00Z | Morning | Morning | 2017-10-15T07:00:00Z | 2017-10-15T19:29:00Z |
| 2017-10-15T10:01:00Z | Morning | Morning | 2017-10-15T07:00:00Z | 2017-10-15T19:29:00Z |
| 2017-10-15T11:01:00Z | Morning | Morning | 2017-10-15T07:00:00Z | 2017-10-15T19:29:00Z |
| 2017-10-15T12:01:00Z | Morning | Morning | 2017-10-15T07:00:00Z | 2017-10-15T19:29:00Z |
| 2017-10-15T13:01:00Z | Morning | Morning | 2017-10-15T07:00:00Z | 2017-10-15T19:29:00Z |
| 2017-10-15T14:01:00Z | Morning | Morning | 2017-10-15T07:00:00Z | 2017-10-15T19:29:00Z |
| 2017-10-15T15:01:00Z | Morning | Morning | 2017-10-15T07:00:00Z | 2017-10-15T19:29:00Z |
| 2017-10-15T16:01:00Z | Morning | Morning | 2017-10-15T07:00:00Z | 2017-10-15T19:29:00Z |
| 2017-10-15T17:01:00Z | Morning | Morning | 2017-10-15T07:00:00Z | 2017-10-15T19:29:00Z |
| 2017-10-15T18:01:00Z | Morning | Morning | 2017-10-15T07:00:00Z | 2017-10-15T19:29:00Z |
| 2017-10-15T19:01:00Z | Morning | Morning | 2017-10-15T07:00:00Z | 2017-10-15T19:29:00Z |
| 2017-10-15T20:01:00Z |   Night |   Night | 2017-10-15T19:30:00Z | 2017-10-15T23:59:00Z |
| 2017-10-15T21:01:00Z |   Night |   Night | 2017-10-15T19:30:00Z | 2017-10-15T23:59:00Z |
| 2017-10-15T22:01:00Z |   Night |   Night | 2017-10-15T19:30:00Z | 2017-10-15T23:59:00Z |
| 2017-10-15T23:01:00Z |   Night |   Night | 2017-10-15T19:30:00Z | 2017-10-15T23:59:00Z |
| 2017-10-16T00:01:00Z |   Night |   Night | 2017-10-16T00:00:00Z | 2017-10-16T06:59:00Z |
| 2017-10-16T01:01:00Z |   Night |   Night | 2017-10-16T00:00:00Z | 2017-10-16T06:59:00Z |
| 2017-10-16T02:01:00Z |   Night |   Night | 2017-10-16T00:00:00Z | 2017-10-16T06:59:00Z |
| 2017-10-16T03:01:00Z |   Night |   Night | 2017-10-16T00:00:00Z | 2017-10-16T06:59:00Z |
| 2017-10-16T04:01:00Z |   Night |   Night | 2017-10-16T00:00:00Z | 2017-10-16T06:59:00Z |
| 2017-10-16T05:01:00Z |   Night |   Night | 2017-10-16T00:00:00Z | 2017-10-16T06:59:00Z |
| 2017-10-16T06:01:00Z |   Night |   Night | 2017-10-16T00:00:00Z | 2017-10-16T06:59:00Z |
| 2017-10-16T07:01:00Z | Morning | Morning | 2017-10-16T07:00:00Z | 2017-10-16T19:29:00Z |
```

Comment: Hi @Used_By_Already, thanks for the answer but the result I want is only to get the percentage. Please advice.

Comment: I am trying to get you to CLARIFY your requirements.... which are not clear now. I was hoping you would take that table, add come columns and tell us - precisely - what you expect for each hour.... this would be called an "expected result". I know you want % at the end, but to get there you need to clarify that table.

Comment: The only not working query when current time is 00:00 AM then We try to query it. I mean query for '07:00' - '19:29' OK, '19:30' - '23:59' OK but not working '19:30' - '23:59' and '00:00' - '06:59'. You can see on this fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5fb75/1/0

Comment: No. I cannot see that at all, all I see is "0%". The part that isn't working is invisible to me. That is why I created the query above.You need to explain what `The only not working query when current time is 00:00 AM` means, and I encourage you to use the table above to populate it with the values you DO WANT. I shall happily delete this answer if you don't think I'm helping.